# Define fromInteger function in Num instance on in Haskell

Tags: haskell

> I tried to make it so that in the console the following
>
> 1 :: AlgebraicGraph Int
>
> Will produce
>
> Vertex 1

```
data AlgebraicGraph a
        = Empty
        | Vertex a
        | Overlay (AlgebraicGraph a) (AlgebraicGraph a)
        | Connect (AlgebraicGraph a) (AlgebraicGraph a)

instance Num a => Num (AlgebraicGraph a) where
    fromInteger x = Vertex x
    (+) x y = Overlay x y
    (*) x y = Connect x y
```

> But when I try fromInteger x = Vertex x, what I get is

```
 Couldn't match type `a' with `Integer'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
    at AlgebraicGraph.hs:120:10-40
  Expected type: AlgebraicGraph a
    Actual type: AlgebraicGraph Integer
* In the expression: Vertex x
  In an equation for `fromInteger': fromInteger x = Vertex x
  In the instance declaration for `Num (AlgebraicGraph a)'
* Relevant bindings include
    fromInteger :: Integer -> AlgebraicGraph a
```

> Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fromInteger x = Vertex x
```

The problem is that `x :: Integer` there, not `Num a => a`. Do this instead:

```
fromInteger x = Vertex (fromInteger x)
```